# KohanaPHP 3 Routing Issues

Tags: routes, kohana

I'm having a route for user controller. This controller has about 20 methods so I don't want to set them manually in routes:

```
Route::set('user', 'user/<action>')
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ));
```

I have also pictures controller (Controller_User_Pictures) with multiple methods that is used to manage users pictures. When I create a route:

```
Route::set('pictures', 'user/pictures/<action>')
        ->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'user',
            'controller' => 'user_pictures',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ));
```

It's not working.

Even if I create a separate controller (Controller_Pictures) and create route it's not working:

```
Route::set('pictures', 'user/pictures/<action>')
        ->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'user',
            'controller' => 'pictures',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ));
```

In all cases it returns error: `Method action_pictures does not exist` which means that router is looking for an action called pictures in user controller which of course is wrong.

The only solution that I'm thinking of, is to define all routes in bootstrap.php file. Do you have better solution?

**Edit**
Second question, do have any idea how to replace underscore with hyphen in any actions (of course in routing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the routes is important; specific routes should come first.

So your url `user/pictures/<action>` is triggering the first route. If you put the pictures-route above the general user-route, it should work just fine.

Another side-note: if you specify directory 'user', your controller would be `Controller_User_Pictures` in `classes/controller/user/pictures.php`

Comment: Yes, you're right. And that's what I thought however there's one small bug that made me thinking wrong. When I do not provide any action in URL (only user/pictures) it's not working (showing the error from my question), if I provide index or any other actions it's working. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Also, expanded my question, if you can take a look, it would be delighted.

Comment: The url `user/pictures` won't work because the action in the route is not optional. A slight change is needed in the route: `'user/pictures(/<action>)'` This way the action part in the route (and the / infront of it) is optional. As for your underscore/hyphen-thing; I don't know for sure. I haven't seen a proper solution nor came across it myself. Underscores translate into directory-separators in Kohana. So it's probably best to not (ab)use those that much.