# PHP Kohana 3.3 Controller Sub Folder

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

I've looked at so many Stackoverflow questions regarding this and none of them seem to solve my problem. I just want to have a admin folder and controllers within those. Here is what my route looks so far

```
/*
 * Set the routes. Each route must have a minimum of a name, a URI and a set of
 * defaults for the URI.
 */
Route::set( 'default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))' )
->defaults( array(
        'controller' => 'dashboard',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ) );

Route::set('admin','admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'dashboard',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Comment: Move the route above the default one - does it work then?

Comment: @kingkero yes... I can't believe that was the problem...

Comment: @kingkero why don't you answer this question so it can be closed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [KohanaPHP 3 Routing Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324047/kohanaphp-3-routing-issues)

Answer (score 0):

As Kingkero said in his comment, move the route above the default one and it will work. if you read the docs on routing properly (I know it takes a while and a few reads for it all to sink in if you're new to it all, I've been there myself) it should be clear that the default route is a catch-all, and that any specific routes you need should come first, and any catch-all type routes after, as they are tried in sequence and when a match is found no more routes are tried.